# Create Scale Onetime object With timezone

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am setting a OneTime Policy in scale group.  When I set the user input time, do I need to set a timezone to retrieve a correct time data?
My timezone is ""Asia/Seoul". What kind of timezone do I need to set to create or edit the object ?

```
Policy pObject = new Policy();
GregorianCalendar gCalender = new GregorianCalendar();
gCalender.setTimeInMillis(userInput_time);

gCalender.setTimeZone(????);

onetime.setDate(gCalender);
pObject.getOneTimeTriggers().add(onetime);
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
GregorianCalendar gCalender = new GregorianCalendar();
gCalender.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Seoul"));
```

Regards

Comment: I already tried this. but when I input 2016-10-20 10:50, it returns "Exactly on 2016-10-20 15:50 GMT+09:00 ". Setting tiemzone as "Asia/Seoul" does not work.

Comment: I think it takes the timezone configured the user settings, Is the settings of your user as "Asia/Seul"?

Comment: Yes, my user setting is "Asia/Seoul".  A weird thing is when I edit the onetime object with "groupService.editObject()", the correct time value is delivered. But Incorrect date is delivered when creating policy with "groupService.createObject()".

Comment: The same millisecond values have been input in editing and creating, but it returns a different date value.

Comment: it looks like an issue in the java client I suggest you to open an issue in the github project